# Conditional navigation with Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multi-page form where the user navigates between the pages using Boostrap tabs. I want to make the tabbing conditional, so that if there are problems with the data they cannot tab to another page. So in effect I want to intercept the navigation, check for validity, and then if OK let the navigation proceed. I've tried using a click handler with event.preventDefault, and the handler runs but the tabbing happens anyway. I figure it must be straightforward to do what I want but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Post the code you've tried to far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the opposite:

1. By default disable all but the first tab (`class="disabled"`).
2. Perform data validation on the fly (as data is being completed by the user), with JavaScript/jQuery.
3. If the validation rules pass, enable the other tab (remove the `disabled` class).

Comment: I ended up using a variant of this technique, i.e., adding the navigation dynamically once validation has succeeded.

Comment: @JohnMoore Cool. However, from user's perspective, I always prefer to see the workflow steps upfront, even though they're disabled. I think that's the most common design, just look at different shopping services, etc... You always see the number of steps: 1. purchase, 2. delivery, 3, billing, 4. confirmation... They don't hide it from you, and there's a good reasoning behind.

Comment: I didn't express myself well there. I meant enabling, rather than adding, the navigation dynamically. The tabs are all visible, they're just non-functional until it's safe to navigate away from the page.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @bostaf recommends you can do something like this...

```
// disable all tabs
$('[data-toggle=tab]').click(function () {
  return false;}
).addClass("text-muted");

var validated = function(tab){
  tab.unbind('click').removeClass('text-muted');
}

//validate inputs on click of button
$('.btn-ok').click(function(){

    var allValid = true;
    // get each input in this tab pane and validate
    $(this).parents('.tab-pane').find('.form-control').each(function(i,e){

        // add some condition(s) to validate each input
        if (valid){
            // validation passed
            allValid = true;
        } else {
            // validation failed
            allValid = false;
        }

    });

    if (allValid) {
        var tabIndex = $(this).parents('.tab-pane').index();
        validated($('[data-toggle]').eq(tabIndex+1));
    }

});
```

http://www.bootply.com/PnCp18N14s